# MVVMで1画面に複数ダイアログView(Datatemplate)の指定方法が知りたい

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog

前提で、MVVMでダイアログ表示を行おうとしています。ダイアログ表示をするため添付ビヘイビアとしてDialogAttachedBehaviorを使用しています。Viewのイベントは使用しません。
MainView.xamlにDatatemplateとしてダイアログのViewを指定しています。
現状、1つのダイアログを表示することはできています。
しかし、Datatemplateの複数指定の方法が分からず、複数のダイアログの表示ができません。
そのため、複数のDatatemplateの指定方法を教えてください。

以下サイトを参考にしました。
http://sourcechord.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/06/234443

MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Apps.DialogApp.App.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Apps.DialogApp.App"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid local:DialogAttachedBehavior.CloseCommand="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}"
      local:DialogAttachedBehavior.WindowViewModel="{Binding DialogVM}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:DialogAttachedBehavior.WindowTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:DialogView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:DialogAttachedBehavior.WindowTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding OpenDialogCommand}" Content="Open" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding CloseDialogForCodeCommand}" Content="ダイアログ閉じる" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : Common.BindableBase
{
    private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            this.message = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DialogViewModel dialogVM;
    public DialogViewModel DialogVM
    {
        get
        {
            return dialogVM;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dialogVM = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand openDialogCommand;
    public DelegateCommand OpenDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return openDialogCommand = openDialogCommand ?? new DelegateCommand(OpenDialog);
        }
    }

    private void OpenDialog(object parameter)
    {
        this.DialogVM = new DialogViewModel() { Message = this.Message };
    }

    private DelegateCommand openDialogCommand2;
    public DelegateCommand OpenDialogCommand2
    {
        get
        {
            return openDialogCommand2 = openDialogCommand2 ?? new DelegateCommand(OpenDialog2);
        }
    }

    private void OpenDialog2(object parameter)
    {
        this.DialogVM = new DialogViewModel2() { Message = this.Message };
    }

    private DelegateCommand closeDialogCommand;
    public DelegateCommand CloseDialogCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return closeDialogCommand = closeDialogCommand ?? new DelegateCommand(CloseDialog);
        }
    }

    private void CloseDialog(object parameter)
    {
        DialogViewModel vm = parameter as DialogViewModel;
        this.Message = vm.Message; 
    }

    private DelegateCommand closeDialogForCodeCommand;
    public DelegateCommand CloseDialogForCodeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return closeDialogForCodeCommand = this.closeDialogForCodeCommand ?? new DelegateCommand(CloseDialogForCode);
        }
    }

    private void CloseDialogForCode(object parameter)
    {
        this.DialogVM = null;
    }
}
```

DialogAttachedBehavior.cs(DelegateCommandはICommandを継承したクラスです)

```
    public class DialogAttachedBehavior
{
    // CloseCommand
    public static DelegateCommand GetCloseCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DelegateCommand)obj.GetValue(CloseCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCloseCommand(DependencyObject obj, DelegateCommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CloseCommandProperty,value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CloseCommand",typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(DialogAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    // WindowTemplate
    public static DataTemplate GetWindowTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (DataTemplate)obj.GetValue(WindowTemplateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWindowTemplate(DependencyObject obj, DataTemplate value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WindowTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WindowTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DialogAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    // Window
    public static Window GetWindow(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Window)obj.GetValue(WindowProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWindow(DependencyObject obj, Window value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WindowProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Window", typeof(Window), typeof(DialogAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    // WindowViewModel
    public static object GetWindowViewModel(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(WindowViewModelProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWindowViewModel(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WindowViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WindowViewModel", typeof(object), typeof(DialogAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnWindowViewModelChanged));

    private static void OnWindowViewModelChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
        if(element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var template = GetWindowTemplate(obj);
        var viewmodel = GetWindowViewModel(obj);

        if(template != null)
        {
            if(viewmodel != null)
            {
                OpenWindow(element);
            }
            else
            {
                CloseWindow(element);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OpenWindow(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var win = GetWindow(element);
        var cmd = GetCloseCommand(element);
        var template = GetWindowTemplate(element);
        var vm = GetWindowViewModel(element);

        if (win == null)
        {
            win = new Window()
            {
                ContentTemplate = template,
                Content = vm,
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                Owner = null
            };


            win.Closed += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    if (cmd.CanExecute(vm))
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(vm);
                    }
                }
                SetWindow(element, null);
            };

            SetWindow(element, win);
            // ダイアログ表示
            win.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // 画面アクティブ化(前面に)
            win.Activate();
        }
    }

    private static void CloseWindow(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var win = GetWindow(element);

        if(win != null)
        {
            win.Close();
            SetWindow(element, null);
        }
    }

    public static bool GetClose(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(CloseProperty);
    }

    public static void SetClose(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CloseProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Close", typeof(bool), typeof(DialogAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnCloseChanged ));

    private static void OnCloseChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = obj as Window;
        if(win == null)
        {
            win = Window.GetWindow(obj);
        }

        if (GetClose(obj))
        {
            win.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
方法としては、Datatemplateをビヘイビアで設定するのをやめて、
MainWindow.xamlのWindow.Resorceに指定しました。
ビヘイビア側で、Window.ResorceのDatatemplateを検索してViewModelに対応するViewを取得するようにしました。

MainView.xamlの変更した箇所

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DialogViewModel">
        <local:DialogView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DialogViewModel2">
        <local:DialogView2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

DialogAttachedBehavior.csの変更した箇所

```
        private static void OnWindowViewModelChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
        if(element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var viewmodel = GetWindowViewModel(obj);

        if (viewmodel != null)
        {
            var template = element.FindResource(viewmodel.GetType().Name);
            if (template != null)
            {
                OpenWindow(element);
            }
            else
            {
                CloseWindow(element);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OpenWindow(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var win = GetWindow(element);
        var cmd = GetCloseCommand(element);
        var vm = GetWindowViewModel(element);
        var template = (DataTemplate)element.FindResource(vm.GetType().Name);

        if (win == null)
        {
            win = new Window()
            {
                ContentTemplate = template,
                Content = vm,
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                Owner = null
            };


            win.Closed += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    if (cmd.CanExecute(vm))
                    {
                        cmd.Execute(vm);
                    }
                }
                SetWindow(element, null);
            };

            SetWindow(element, win);
            // ダイアログ表示
            win.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            // 画面アクティブ化(前面に)
            win.Activate();
        }
    }
```